# Editing RTF files

Tags: java, swing, rtf, javax.swing.text

I have been able to read RTF files with `RTFEditorKit` but I want something more. I want to be able to change text to bold or italic and to change font size just like MS Word does. I want to be able to edit the RTF and changes made should be visible if I open the RTF file with another application.

How can I?

Comment: *"I want.."* We want (or more accurately **need**) a question for this **Q** & A site. Voting to close as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: That would lead me to change my close vote from 'no question' to 'too broad'. What research have you done? What have you  tried?

Comment: I see. Please close it and let me ask another question somewhere else. I think this question is bad enough